# How can I get the contents of the text box below and display the retrieved text on the label when I press the button?

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d5Zp.jpg)

Please tell me what kind of code to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you've already created the reference for the textbox as `TextView`. Now you need to create a new `IBOutlet` for the label. Once you have the reference to the label you can get the text value from the textview and show it in the label.

```
@IBAction func display(_sender) {
    self.labelView.text = self.TextView.text
    //if you want to clear the textview
    self.TextView.text = ""
}
```

Comment: sorry,『Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'labelView'』will come out

Comment: @K.mit did you create the `IBOutlet` with the name `labelView` on the label?

Comment: @ jay mayu  next error      self.yourlabel.text = self.TextView.text  in part
 Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: As the error says one of the objects is not properly initialised. Can you paste your current code in question please so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Create outlet for your label

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourlabel: UILabel!
```

On Button Action right code to set the value to label.

```
@IBAction func display(_sender) {

yourlabel.text = self.TextView.text
}
```